# Controlling an NSArrayController and Core data relations

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5

I am new to stackoverflow because I almost never ask questions in forums as there are plenty of questions out there already answered. However my head is about to explode from trying to figure out how to do this app.

First I do this using XCode 4.5.2 for OSX 10.8 deployment of a personal (that is for my use only) double entry accounting software.

Each accounting entry consists of a header of various text fields such as the entry date, a serial number, etc. which I created an Entity called "Entry". Also each such entry has multiple lines such as the various accounts related to that entry, amounts, etc. called an Entity "EntryLine" linked in the model nice and easy.

The thing is that I intended to use text field for the basic header info and below it a linked Table View for each of the line. Being an accounting software there are several checks (validations) that I need to make and I need full control of what is going on. Already tried binding two array controllers, one for each entity and linking the two and saving them to the sqlite file but to no avail!

Now I have an app with just the header up and running by manually getting and setting the info in the top text fields as I please and saving them to the file. But I have no idea how to do the part with the Entry Lines in the Table view. Can I do that manually too or is it better to do bindings through an array controller?

Also tried already with array controller but I get "Table View Cell" when I add a new line in the table. Any ideas on that?

In the Table View there is also an "Account Name" part that is NOT part of the EntryLine entity but my intention is to obtain this information from another entity called "Account" that stores the Account Number and Account Name. On input of the account number that is, the app would skip the name field and move to particulars for input but also bring up the name of the account already inputted. Is this even possible?

Sorry for being a bit vague in my questions but I come from routine program oriented languages and not object oriented one, though I have some Java experience. Any help would be appreciated. No screenshot sorry as I am not yet allowed:(

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the "Table View Cell" shown when I add a new row as I have used "view based" table view instead of "cell based".